# Edit drupal register user and add users function

Tags: function, drupal, addition, edit

I want to add user Username, Email and password into 2 databases(one drupal DB and My_log DB).
how can i  find drupal add users function and register function, to edit this and insert my codes to this function.
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [hook_user_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7) hook.

with that hook you can handle the data right after it was inserted into the database... so here would be a good point of doing some extra database stuff for your second database...

i would recommend you to not hack the core of drupal, because of several reasons (like: what if you update the core? then all your changes are gone.. and so on..)
just because of that reason, drupal got the hook system :)